# Error not bubbling up from delete trigger

Tags: apex, error-messages, before-trigger, delete

I need to prevent deletion of our dummy account, which is part of the Lead conversion process under certain conditions.  And it *does* prevent deletion.  However, the error I am adding to the account record does not bubble up to the UI.

Am I doing something wrong or is this an expected behavior?  Do I need to move my code to "isUpdate" and check the "IsDeleted" flag instead?

Code:

```
if (Trigger.isBefore) {
    // Prevent dummy account deletion
    if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
            if (a.Name == 'DO NOT DELETE') a.addError('This account may not be deleted. It is part of the Lead conversion process.');
        }
    }
```

Actual error:

> There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to
>   edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your
>   administrator for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use `Trigger.old` in case of `delete` operation to be able to display your custom error message. This is from the [Trigger Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm?search_text=adderror) documentation (emphasis mine):

> Triggers can be used to prevent DML operations from occurring by calling the `addError()` method on a record or field. When used on `Trigger.new` records in `insert` and `update` triggers, **and on `Trigger.old` records in `delete` triggers, the custom error message is displayed in the application interface and logged**.